# How to redirect selected list correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a few issue with my input- and I'm using [awesomplete autocomplete plugin](http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete) the issue is with my function..if I clicked input before selected text then my page is redirecting..for example type a `Fa` and don't select text only click on input and you are gonna see how my page is redirecting

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
        if (!$("#srehberText").length) return false;
        var input = document.getElementById("srehberText");

    // Show label but insert value into the input:
    new Awesomplete(input, {
        list: [
            { label: "<img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRUxdD-Q4nIx3uIg9jBCe1oT5a9MHuWY5_pW4FoZSU-nQd1Y_WJPQ'/> Facebook", value: "https://www.facebook.com/" },
            { label: "<img src='https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/thumb/2/25/Pounce_icon.png/16px-Pounce_icon.png?version=77c984fc4a9c8ca491ead081322fa738'/> Youtube", value: "https://www.youtube.com/" },
            { label: "China", value: "CN" },
            { label: "United States", value: "US" }
        ]
    });



    
    // You can search for a better version
 $(document).find('.awesomplete').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($('#srehberText').val())
    window.location = $('#srehberText').val();
  //console.log($('#myinput').val());
});
});
```

```css
input{
  padding:15px;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input id="srehberText" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is probably because of the click listener you've set on `.awesomplete`, you're changing the location if the input has any value.

Comment: yes  exactyl as you said..how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is probably because of the click listener you've set on `.awesomplete`, you're changing the location if the input has any value. You can fix that by adding a click listener to the input and stopping the event's propagation.

Eg:

```
$("#srehberText").clock(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    if (!$("#srehberText").length) return false;
    var input = document.getElementById("srehberText");

    new Awesomplete(input, {
        list: [
            { label: "<img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRUxdD-Q4nIx3uIg9jBCe1oT5a9MHuWY5_pW4FoZSU-nQd1Y_WJPQ'/> Facebook", value: "https://www.facebook.com/" },
            { label: "<img src='https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/thumb/2/25/Pounce_icon.png/16px-Pounce_icon.png?version=77c984fc4a9c8ca491ead081322fa738'/> Youtube", value: "https://www.youtube.com/" },
            { label: "China", value: "CN" },
            { label: "United States", value: "US" }
        ]
    });

   $("#srehberText").click(function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
   });     

   $(document).find('.awesomplete').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($('#srehberText').val())
      window.location = $('#srehberText').val();
   });
});
```

```css
input{
  padding:15px;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input id="srehberText" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.js"></script>
```

Stopping the event's propagation seems to work although, I'm not sure what this is supposed to do:

```
$(document).find('.awesomplete').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($('#srehberText').val())
    window.location = $('#srehberText').val();
});
```

I took a quick look at the library's documentation and there seems to be a better way of doing what you're trying to do. It seems that the library generates an event when a item is selected `awesomplete-selectcomplete`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    if (!$("#srehberText").length) return false;
    var input = document.getElementById("srehberText");

    new Awesomplete(input, {
        list: [
            { label: "<img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRUxdD-Q4nIx3uIg9jBCe1oT5a9MHuWY5_pW4FoZSU-nQd1Y_WJPQ'/> Facebook", value: "https://www.facebook.com/" },
            { label: "<img src='https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/thumb/2/25/Pounce_icon.png/16px-Pounce_icon.png?version=77c984fc4a9c8ca491ead081322fa738'/> Youtube", value: "https://www.youtube.com/" },
            { label: "China", value: "CN" },
            { label: "United States", value: "US" }
        ]
    });

    $("#srehberText").on("awesomplete-selectcomplete", function(e){
       window.location = e.originalEvent.text.value;
    });
});
```

```css
input{
  padding:15px;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input id="srehberText" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi it's very well as I expected but now redirecting it's not working correctly it work sometimes

Comment: @recruit_man I've edited my answer. I wasn't sure what your code was supposed to do at first but now I think I do and I think I found a better solution.

Comment: I don't know how will I thank you..thank you very, very much!